# how to not upload empty file inputs

Tags: php, file, upload

I have many file inputs in my HTML form. All of them are in an array.

For example :

```
<input type="file" name="attach[]">
<input type="file" name="attach[]">
<input type="file" name="attach[]">
<input type="file" name="attach[]">
```

How can I find empty inputs in PHP?

Comment: Sorry For The Language , I dont understand English very well

Answer (score 1):

use this in your for each when you are uploading the file

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES['attach'][$i]))
{

//upload function

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the fields (even the empty ones) get sent to the server and each field will have an array entry with its information (`tmp_name`, `name`, `size`, `error`, ...) although it's empty.

Just check `$_FILES['attach']['error'][$i]` against the `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` (int: 4) constant.

For more information about file upload error messages see [the official PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Please note that for a bunch of files with the same name `<input type="file" name="attach[]">` the array will look like this (in this case for three file input fields):

```
$_FILES['attach'] => array(
    'name' => array(
        0 => 'File 1.jpg',
        1 => 'File 2.pdf',
        2 => ''
    ),

    'error' => array(
        0 => 0,
        1 => 0,
        2 => 4
    ),

    'tmp_name' => array(
        0 => 'foo',
        1 => 'bar',
        2 => ''
    )

    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking the size, and if it's bigger than 0, then uploading it or handling it in the way you see fit

```
foreach($_FILES['attach']['size'] as $file) {
    if($file > 0) {
        // Upload
    }
}
```